# Como encuentro archivo en directorio de proyecto PHP

Tags: php

Estoy descargando el repositorio del "CRM dolibar" que esta escrito en PHP desde Github, decidí descargar archivo por archivo comenzando por el index.php que se encuentra en la carpeta htdocs. A medida que voy descargando pruebo en el servidor localhost y voy chequeando que archivos son requeridos, y asi voy descargando del repositorio, pero llego un punto donde no se donde esta el archivo que me pide.

El repositorio lo encunetran aqui.

https://github.com/PabloCabeza/dolibarr/tree/develop/htdocs

y el archivo que no encuentro es solicitado por el directorio htdocs/install/inc.php

No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\Dolibarr\install\inc.php on line 48

esta es la linea de código que lo solicita

require_once ADODB_PATH.'adodb-time.inc.php';

el valor de la constante ADODB_PATH = /usr/share/php/adodb/

y el problema se viene que no encuentro esa ruta dentro del directorio principal htdocs de Dolibar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa (por lo que observo) es que los **php** están escritos para ambiente Unix/Linux; por eso tiene `ADODB_PATH = /usr/share/php/adodb/` (no profundice en el código) será cuestión veas para Windows que es ese `php/adobd` que se requiere, lo instales (y configures) así mismo cambies la ruta allí por la que corresponda a la instalación en Windows.

Por cierto aquí al parecer para Windows https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php/Dolibarr_for_Windows_(DoliWamp)

> Desde luego puede que este no sea el único cambio que requieras ajustar conforme al entorno donde lo estas usando y queriendo ejecutar.

Comment: Ahh bien gracias, leeré acerca de eso que dices.